# Trying to get a specific value from db, for the current page

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, nextgen-gallery

I am trying to get the title from Nextgen Gallery.

This is the code I have:

```
<?php 
global $nggdb;
$gallery = $nggdb->get_gallery(4, 'sortorder', 'ASC', true, 1, 0);
foreach($gallery as $image) {
    echo $image->alttext;
}
?>
```

I know that like this I get to the db, and I am also able to get the first image's title.

But the problem is that I am not getting the current page/image title. Only the first one.

How can I get a dynamic title (alttext) and not only the first one?

Comment: use count($gallery) to be sure that your array contains more than 1 node.

Comment: What do you mean? I don't need more than 1. I need the correct one for the current image.

Comment: sorry but now i have totally no idea what you want.

Comment: i solved it using the basic tutorial about db that wp provides. thanks a lot